# Why is this dropdown selection not rerouting to the new page on download

Tags: onclick, dropdown

```
<html>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="dropdown"></div>

<script>


function goToNewPage()
{
    var url = document.getElementById('dropdown').value;
    if(url != 'none') {
        window.location = url;
    }
}

jSuites.dropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown'), {
data:[
 
{value:"link", text: 'Name'},
',


// (...)
],
autocomplete: true,
width:'800px',


});
</script>
<input type=button value="Download Report" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

</html>
```

I was expecting that once i click Download Report, I would be rerouted to the report but that is not the case. I placed the url in the link and on click it just resets the existing page any thoughts on this?